# Update models fields thanks to form?

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE THANKS TO @ruddra**

```
class CheckoutDetail(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Sugargroup
    context_object_name = 'sugargroup'
    template_name = 'checkout_detail.html'
    form_class = CreateSugarChatForm
    validation_form_class = LaunchSugargroupForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CheckoutDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        context['validation_form'] = self.get_form(self.validation_form_class) #self.validation_form_class()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.sugargroup = self.object
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalid(form)
            
    def form_valide(self, validation_form):
        if validation_form.is_valid():
            validation_form.instance.sugargroup = self.object
            #validation_form.instance.seller = self.request.user
            validation_form.save()
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valide(validation_form)
        else:
            return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_invalide(validation_form)    

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        validation_form = self.validation_form_class(request.POST) #or validation_form = self.get_form(self.validation_form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        elif validation_form.is_valid(): 
            return self.form_valide(validation_form)
        else:
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('checkout:checkout_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

template

```
{% crispy form %}
{% crispy validation_form %}
```

**EDIT: issue about second form (validation_form create a new channel after completing it with post method)**

is it possible to just update the current channel (with is_active = True)?

```
class Sugargroup(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sugargroup_seller")
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Make it happen', default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False, unique=True)
```

the logic is consumer create a channel and seller (if he accepts) launch it (make is_active = true)

**INITIAL ISSUE**

I'm going to end up tearing my hair out. I don't understand why this view returns the same form (CreateSugarChatForm: which works well) for both forms. Could someone please help me? But I don't know why validation_form appears as CreateSugarChatFormlooking.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CheckoutDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['form'] = self.get_form()
    context['validation_form'] = self.get_form() #change here (because of same validation_form)
    return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `self.get_form()` for both `form` and `validation_form` variables in context:

```
context['form'] = self.get_form()
context['validation_form'] = self.get_form()
```

Change it like this:

```
context['form'] = self.get_form()
context['validation_form'] = self.validator_form_class()
```

Finally to fix the post method, maybe you can try like this:

```
def form_valide(self, validation_form):
    validation_form.instance.user = self.request.user
    validation_form.save()
    return super(CheckoutDetail, self).form_valid(validation_form)  

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
   self.object = self.get_object()
   form = self.get_form()
   validation_form = self.validator_form_class(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
       return self.form_valid(form)
   elif validation_form.is_valid(): 
       return self.form_valide(validation_form)
   else:
       return self.form_invalid(form)
```

### Update

As per suggestion of @DmitryBelaventsev, you can try like this:

```
# get_context_data method
context['form'] = self.get_form()
context['validation_form'] = self.get_form(self.validator_form_class)

# post method
validation_form = self.get_form(self.validator_form_class)
```

Comment: You should also pass the form kwargs during instantiation like `self.validtor_form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())`. How do you think?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i'm trying with your new solve to overcome the issue of posting

Comment: Better use `get_form()` method. I will update the answer shortly I @DmitryBelaventsev

Comment: Thanks for all your work again :) when I login with seller account to launch the channel after completing the form I got this 'super' object has no attribute 'form_valide'